# How can set a width to a single column in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to know how can I set the width of a single column - If I have several columns the width of each one of them looks fine but when i have only one column it looks very wide.
Thanks,
Ron

here is my example chart- all I want is to be able to define the width of this single column:

Comment: You might want to look at the [pointWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointWidth) option. It might not be the perfect solution, but its a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from suggested pointWidht, you should set [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.column.pointRange)

Answer (score 1):

You can also affect the column width by setting the x axis scale.

If you set a max x value as if there were mulitple columns, the width will adjust.

Doing this in conjunction with the pointRange will be very effective ways to control the width while maintaining proper ration to the axis - whereas the pointWidth option will over ride the relationship to the axis values.